# Turn off partition discovery Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to turn off partition discovery? I'm trying to prevent columns to be automatically added to my dataframe.

For example

If I have a folder structure like this

```
/data/year=2018/table=foo/....
```

I wouldn't want year / table as columns in my read in dataframe if I read from data

```
spark.read.orc("/data/*")
```

It should look something like

```
col_1, col_2, ....
```

And not

```
col_1, col_2, ..., year, table
```

Comment: How about reading the Hive table directly via `spark.read.table`?